# "overflow-y: scroll" makes nested divs with "position: absolute" disappear

Tags: html, css

i have a vertical bar with items that have a info field right next to them. The info fields i position as absolute. Now when i make the bar scrollable with "overflow-y: scroll" the items disappear. But according to developer tools they are still there. Changing the z-index has no effect. I created a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/x8h69ghj/1/

css:

```
#bar {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  width: 60px;
  max-height: 200px;
  /* XXX removing this will show the .info divs */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="bar">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="button">      button    </div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="button">      button    </div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="button">      button    </div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="button">      button    </div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="button">      button    </div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="button">      button    </div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="button">      button    </div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Removing the "overflow-y: scroll" from #bar will make the .item divs to show.

This is probably a pretty basic css question but i can't figure out what the problem is. I'd really appreciate any hints about why the .item divs are not shown when the bar is scrollable.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I understand it right...you have to scroll to the right to see your info texts or set #bar width to 150px

Answer (score 1):

Your `.info` class has `position: absolute` and `left: 100px;`:

```
.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

`left: 100px;` will in this case act like an *offset*: The original position is *inside* the parent element (in this case #bar, since `.item` has no width settings), but `left: 100px;` moves it 100px to the right.

`position: absolute` makes it possible that it's still show. If you allow a scrollbar (with `overflow-y: scroll`), the offset position is accessible by scrolling, if not, it simply is shown outside the parent element (due to the offset). If you change the parent's width (`#bar`) to 160px, you'll also see the info divs (without scrollbars)...

Answer (score 1):

@senorpedro All elements are present on UI. Scroll right and you will see them. Quick fix is to increse width of bar class from width: 60px; to width: 160px; you could adjust it according to your needs.

```
#bar {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  width: 160px; /* changed */
  max-height: 100px;
  /* XXX removing this will show the .info divs */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vmk8fcgv/